# How to count the occurence of semantic tags loaded by UCREL Semantic Analysis System (USAS)

Tags: python, pandas, semantics

I loaded the UCREL Semantic Analysis System (USAS) to some lyrics. An example of result follows:

Because Z5/A2.2
that Z8
is A3
okay A5.1
do A1.1.1
not Z6
stop T2-
me Z8mf
right Z4

Every word gets a semantic tag. All these tags are on http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/usas/semtags.txt

I need to count the occurrence of each tag. So, I tried to code using Pandas. That is not big deal. The problem is I need to count the tags until the second number after the dot (.). For example, "A1.1" , "A1.1.1" or "A1.1.2" must be counted as A1.1

The initial code I ran is below, but it simply counts all the occurrences of the tags and does not have the condition I explained above.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.common
from pprint import pprint
import glob

files = glob.glob("/[folder name]/**/*.txt", recursive = True)

files = list(filter(lambda file: os.stat(file).st_size > 0, files))

for file in files:
  data = pd.read_csv(file, engine='python', encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False, header=None, usecols=[1], sep=' ')
  data[1].value_counts().reset_index().to_csv(str(file) +'_totals.txt')
```

How can I add the condition I need, please?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) then keep the first values up to 2, then [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html#pandas-series-str-join) back together:

```
out = df[1].str.split('.').str[:2].str.join('.').value_counts().reset_index()
```

or with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

```
out = df[1].map(lambda s: '.'.join(s.split('.')[:2])).value_counts().reset_index()
```

`out`:

```
  index  1
0  A1.5  3
1  A1.1  2
2  A1.4  1
3  A1.3  1
4  A1.6  1
5  A1.7  1
6  A1.2  1
```

*Note, `rsplit` with a max split length cannot be used here because then `A1.5` would be converted to `A1` instead of staying as `A1.5`.

---

Sample Data Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['A1.1.1', 'A1.1.2', 'A1.2', 'A1.3', 'A1.4', 'A1.5',
                       'A1.5.1', 'A1.5.2', 'A1.6', 'A1.7']})
```

`df`:

```
        1
0  A1.1.1
1  A1.1.2
2    A1.2
3    A1.3
4    A1.4
5    A1.5
6  A1.5.1
7  A1.5.2
8    A1.6
9    A1.7
```

---

Breakdown of steps:

```
df[1].str.split('.')
```

```
0    [A1, 1, 1]
1    [A1, 1, 2]
2       [A1, 2]
3       [A1, 3]
4       [A1, 4]
5       [A1, 5]
6    [A1, 5, 1]
7    [A1, 5, 2]
8       [A1, 6]
9       [A1, 7]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

```
df[1].str.split('.').str[:2]
```

```
0    [A1, 1]
1    [A1, 1]
2    [A1, 2]
3    [A1, 3]
4    [A1, 4]
5    [A1, 5]
6    [A1, 5]
7    [A1, 5]
8    [A1, 6]
9    [A1, 7]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

```
df[1].str.split('.').str[:2].str.join('.')
```

```
0    A1.1
1    A1.1
2    A1.2
3    A1.3
4    A1.4
5    A1.5
6    A1.5
7    A1.5
8    A1.6
9    A1.7
Name: 1, dtype: object
```